# Fixed nav-bar goes on top of vertical scroll browser sidebar

Tags: html, css

My navbar goes on top of the browser's vertical scrolling bar.

I do not really know at what point on my project this happened but I gave my nav-bar a fixed position and a 100% width with a z-index: 99.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thnaks in advance, happy coding!

Here is my HTML code:

```
<header class="showcase">

<nav class="nav-bar">
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="../src/images/logo.svg" alt="LBH Logo" class="nav-logo"></a>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#abt">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#srv">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#soc">Social</a></li>
    <li><a href="#inf">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="nav-social">
    <i class="fab fa-instagram "></i>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="hamburger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

And here is my css:

```
.showcase {
  height: 120vh;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), rgba(0, 0, 0, .9) ), 
  url(../src/images/showcase-background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.showcase .nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  background-color: var(--branding);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 90;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  top: 0;
}

.nav-logo {  /*CHECK WHEN UPLOADING LOGO*/
  width: 14rem;
  margin: auto .5rem;
}

.showcase .nav-bar .nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
}

.showcase .nav-bar .nav-links li {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.showcase .nav-bar .nav-links a {
  color: var(--lightgrey);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links li:hover,
.nav-links li:focus {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.showcase .nav-bar .nav-social {
  margin: 0 2rem .5rem 2rem;
}

.showcase .nav-bar .nav-social a {
  margin: 0 .5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--lightgrey);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

I would like to ask as well how do you do to display fontawesome icons? i inserted the html piece of code but I'm not able to give them any width so i can not see them.

Comment: Are you saying you WANT it to go on thop of the vertical scroll bar?  That is possible by breaking up the body into scrollable and non-scrollable sections. If you DON'T want that to happen, and it IS happening, what browser are you using?  Is the same behavior happening on all browsers?

Comment: You could add the relevant parts of your code in your answer so that we can see [a reproduction of the behavior](http://sscce.org/) you experience. That way you help us help you, and you might find the problem that way yourself.

Comment: Sorry I meant that it IS happening and do NOT want it to. Just checked in another browser and it is happening too.